# What is the relation between a system of nonlinear equation and the minimization of a function from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, logic, numerical-methods

I was reading numerical analysis by Burden and Faires and found the following text that I didn't quite understand:

[image]

To understand the above I was trying to express it as an implication. Is the above excerpt equivalent to saying:

If $g$ has a minimum value of zero then the system of nonlinear equations $F(x) = 0$ is satisfied?

Is it **always** an if and only if implication?

Answer (score 1):

"precisely when" is another way of saying "if and only if". For real-valued functions, it is an iff relation:

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a root of $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, for every $i=1,2,\dotsc,m$, i.e.
$$ f_i(x)=0, \quad i=1,\dotsc,m. $$
Then
$$ g(x) := \sum_{i=1}^m (f_i(x))^2 = 0, $$
obviously.

Conversely, suppose $x$ is not a root of all the $f_i$. Then there must be an integer $j$ between $1$ and $m$ so that $f_j(x) \neq 0$, and hence $g(x) \geqslant (f_j(x))^2 >0$, where both inequalities follow since $y^2$ is nonnegative, and zero if and only if $y=0$.